# Accessing random SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

The application I'm designing will have to be able to access any MS or Oracle database through the network, will have to read all the databases inside the database, list all the tables.

In the end, the user must be able to download a whole table, and load it into the application.

The user will have to insert some parameters :

1. Ip address and port
2. Login and password.

Then he will have to choose the database, and then he will have to choose the table.

I've looked up through the internet to find something almost out of the box, and the best result I've found is actually Dapper (http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Ain't there any better library that could meet my needs?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the `DbConnection` / `DbCommand` and such that are in the `System.Data` namespace? Not sure why you even mention `Dapper` which is an ORM and as such orthogonal to what you are asking.

Comment: All of this is potentially do-able with the SQL Server SMO, at least for the SQL Server databases.

Comment: @AnnL., yes and no. No because the OP needs to be able to connect to Oracle.

Comment: @Oded, didn't mean to literally repeat what you did. I guess we were just thinking along the same lines. :D

Comment: @neoistheone - no problem - great minds and all that ;)

Comment: I can use DbCommand, and any other tool. But the task  I have to achieve seemed to me usual. So in place than writing my own library, I though there might have had some libraries already existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found happyness using DbProviderFactory.

I've created a class that creates connexion strings, and that has a property that return the invariant name of the connexion (eg :  "System.Data.SqlClient").

I use this invariant name and this connexion string that way :

```
 this.Factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connexionStringBuilder.InvariantName);
 this.Connection = Factory.CreateConnection();
 Connection.ConnectionString = connexionStringBuilder.ConnexionString;
```

And then, I have all the ADO.Net queries that I had in the past.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *library* that will meet your needs. You're building a database browsing tool, like SSMS, so Dapper is only a means to an end to get data in a dynamic fashion. However, you could just as easily do it with basic ADO.NET. The `DataTable` is a *very* dynamic structure and quite capable of what you need.

In fact, though I **love** Dapper, I would argue that if I were in your shoes I'd just use ADO.NET because you could abstract your interaction to using just the interfaces: `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` for example.

Comment: I think I will follow your ideas, and create my own library

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:
I agree with the idea of using ADO.NET.  And getting back to the interfaces that SqlConnection and the ODP.NET share.

A few ideas:

[IoC Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488308/UsingplusUnityplusforplusIoCplusandplusDI)

and

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA
```

Google that.  It is what the standard is for different RDBMS.

My guess is that you could write 2 "Concretes" that implement the same abstract class (see IoC link above)... where the abstract class has "common logic"...but then you have a "safety value" if something does work exactly the same between the 2 RDBMS.

But since your results will be dynamic, in the sense you won't know ahead of time what the tables/columns, a DataTable isn't a bad idea.

A different idea is to look at this, the "Dynamic Data" project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

But I don't know (maybe not) if that ever got an implementation for Oracle, probably just Sql Server.

Comment: Oracle works with Dynamic Data?  Maybe.  http://joegilldotcom.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-dynamic-data-and-oracle.html

Answer (score 1):

Before you go rolling your own, I would suggest you take a look at the Microsoft Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block; it builds on ADO.Net but provides a database agnostic API for applications to code against. I've used it against both Sql Server and Oracle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx

Comment: I'll read a bit on this library during the week-end, thx for the suggestion

Comment: I think the EnterpriseLibrary was built using the MS Oracle client, which is now deprecated.  You'll have to see if someone has done an EnterpriseLIbrary.Data update for the ODP.NET (Oracle's client).